# Create Audit Record Using EF4.0

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I am trying to create an audit record for historical purpose I found this code from the following article.

```
List<sysaudit> auditTrailList = new List<sysaudit>();
            IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> changes =  ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified);
            foreach (ObjectStateEntry stateEntryEntity in changes)
            {
                if (!stateEntryEntity.IsRelationship &&
                        stateEntryEntity.Entity != null &&
                            !(stateEntryEntity.Entity is sysaudit))
                {//is a normal entry, not a relationship
                    sysaudit audit = pamsContext.AuditTrailFactory(stateEntryEntity, "");
                    auditTrailList.Add(audit);
                }
            }
            if (auditTrailList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var audit in auditTrailList)
                {//add all audits
                    this.AddToDBAudit(audit);
                }
            }
```

It complains that an object reference is required for the non static field method or property entity state but I have that already reference in code here is my using clauses.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    using System.IO;
    using System.Data.Objects;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

**This is the line its complaining about**

```
IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> changes = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Deleted | EntityState.Modified);
```

Comment: is the pamsContext object initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EntityState on that line should refer to the System.Data.EntityState enumeration. Can you hover over one of the mentions of EntityState to verify this?

Given the compilation error you mention, I suspect your class also contains a non-static field or property called EntityState.

If so, you will need to change the line in question to fully-qualify the namespace, i.e.:

```
IEnumerable<ObjectStateEntry> changes = ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.EntityState.Added | System.Data.EntityState.Deleted | System.Data.EntityState.Modified);
```